# Get a attribute using the value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object listing keyCodes:

```
var keyCodes = {
    "a": 97, "b": 98, "c": 99, "d": 100, "e": 101, "f": 102,
    "g": 103, "h": 104, "i": 105, "j": 106, "k": 107, "l": 108,
    "m": 109, "n": 110, "o": 111, "p": 112, "q": 113, "r": 114,
    "s": 115, "t": 116, "u": 117, "v": 118, "w": 119, "x": 120,
    "y": 121, "z": 122
};
```

But I need to reference the value, not the attribute. How efficiently can I do
this without rewriting the whole object?

Comment: Where you want to reference the values ?

Comment: `keyCodes` is an `Object`, not an `Array`

Comment: Do you mean to swap the key and value in an object?

Comment: You just want to reference the value only for few of the keyCodes or all of them?

Comment: Let me explain. I want to get the _attribute of the object_ according to the value. In this case, the value is keyCode. So, i want to search the object to find the correct attribute for the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be a bit silly, but i'm assuming you want to get the key based on the number value? (over the keyCodes), probably want to pass in multiple values in the func, typecheck the values (between 97-122)

idk tho;

```
var keyCodes = {
  "a": 97, "b": 98, "c": 99, "d": 100, "e": 101, "f": 102,
  "g": 103, "h": 104, "i": 105, "j": 106, "k": 107, "l": 108,
  "m": 109, "n": 110, "o": 111, "p": 112, "q": 113, "r": 114,
  "s": 115, "t": 116, "u": 117, "v": 118, "w": 119, "x": 120,
  "y": 121, "z": 122
};

var getkey = function(value) {
  for (key in keyCodes) { 
    if (keyCodes[key] == value) return key;
  }
}

getkey(122) // returns 'z';
```

Answer (score 1):

Generate a new object where property names are the value and values are the property name where use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method to generate the new object.

```js
var keyCodes = {
    "a": 97, "b": 98, "c": 99, "d": 100, "e": 101, "f": 102,
    "g": 103, "h": 104, "i": 105, "j": 106, "k": 107, "l": 108,
    "m": 109, "n": 110, "o": 111, "p": 112, "q": 113, "r": 114,
    "s": 115, "t": 116, "u": 117, "v": 118, "w": 119, "x": 120,
    "y": 121, "z": 122
  };

var res = Object.keys(keyCodes).reduce(function(obj, k) {
  obj[keyCodes[k]] = k;
  return obj;
}, {})

console.log(res[121])
console.log(res[106])
console.log(res[110])
```

Comment: OP's post: `How efficiently can I do this without rewriting the whole object?`

Comment: @ryanlutgen I find that statement from the OP to be confusing. Perhaps they just don't want to hard-code another object.

Answer (score 1):

You can get `array of values` using `Object.values`

```
var values = Object.values(keyCodes);
console.log(values[0]);
```

And if you want a `single value` you can do this

```
var a = keyCodes["a"];
console.log(a);
```

If you want to get single `property name` from `value` you can try this

```
var val = 110; 
var propName;
for (var prop in keyCodes) {
if (keyCodes[prop] == val) {
   propName = prop;
   break;
  }
}
console.log(propName);
```